# multiindex column and rows match if the column and row names are similar and exclude the values from adding in those cell python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I need the cells excluded from summation when the top level of the multiindex (country1 and Country2) are the same in the row and columns

```
import pandas as pd
label_columns1 = ['Country1','Country2']
label_columns2 = ['agri1', 'agri2']
label_rows1 = ['Country1','Country2']
label_rows2 = ['agri1', 'agri2']

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4]], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([label_rows1,label_rows2]), 
                     columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([label_columns1, label_columns2 ]))
df
                     Country1     Country2
                   agri1  agri2   agri1  agri2  
Country1    agri1   1      2      3       4
            agri2   1      2      3       4
Country2    agri1   1      2      3       4
            agri2   1      2      3       4
```

I know this will give me the row-wise sum and a new column

```
df[('Total',"Vlaue")] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

df

```
                     Country1     Country2  Total
                   agri1  agri2   agri1  agri2 Value    
Country1    agri1   1      2      3       4     10
            agri2   1      2      3       4     10
Country2    agri1   1      2      3       4     10
            agri2   1      2      3       4     10
```

What I really want and have been trying hard was only to add the cells if the column and row index is not the same. Which in this case for example the first row will be 7. my data frame is big and too much rows and columns.
What i have tried so far

```
for col in df.columns:
    for row in df.index:
        if col != row:
            df[('Total',"Vlaue")] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

which gives me unintended results but I guess i am close
My expected result should look like

```
                     Country1     Country2      Total
                   agri1  agri2   agri1  agri2  Value   
Country1    agri1   1      2      3       4     (3+4) = 7
            agri2   1      2      3       4     (3+4) = 7
Country2    agri1   1      2      3       4     (1+2) = 3
            agri2   1      2      3       4     (1+2) = 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mask the values where index is same as the column label, then calculate sum along `axis=1`

```
ix = df.index.get_level_values(0)
cx = df.columns.get_level_values(0)

m = ix.values[:, None] == cx.values
df[('Total', 'Value')] = df.mask(m).sum(axis=1)
```

---

```
               Country1       Country2       Total
                  agri1 agri2    agri1 agri2 Value
Country1 agri1        1     2        3     4   7.0
         agri2        1     2        3     4   7.0
Country2 agri1        1     2        3     4   3.0
         agri2        1     2        3     4   3.0
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks you are a saviour. i tried with a little more data it works perfectly as I want it. i will try it In a big dataframe.

Comment: Dear how can i solve the same problem with a index having yearly values but the column is same. valueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be x: given y. do i have to open a new question? @Shubham

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way:

```
(df.join(
    df.groupby(level=0,axis=1).sum()
    .rsub(df.sum(axis=1),axis=0)
    .droplevel(0)
    .stack()
    .swaplevel()
    .loc[lambda x: ~x.index.duplicated()]
    .rename(('Total','Value'))))
```

Output:

```
               Country1       Country2       Total
                  agri1 agri2    agri1 agri2 Value
Country1 agri1        1     2        3     4     7
         agri2        1     2        3     4     7
Country2 agri1        1     2        3     4     3
         agri2        1     2        3     4     3
```