# elementwise division with panel data df.div(level=?). index level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sample Data

```
arrays1 = [['country1','country1','country1','country1','country2', 'country2', 'country2', 'country2'],
           [2000, 2001, 2000, 2001,2000, 2001, 2000, 2001],
           ['agri1','agri1', 'cons2','cons2', 'agri1','agri1', 'cons2','cons2']]
arrays = [['country1', 'country1', 'country2', 'country2'],
          ['agri1', 'cons2', 'agri1', 'cons2']]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays1, names=('country','Year','sector'))
columns1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('country','sector'))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[24, 20, 30, 20],[16, 14, 10, 25],[28, 22, 6, 28],
                   [11, 10, 10, 4],[6, 7, 12, 16],[19, 24, 6, 9],
                   [22, 9, 10, 15],[9, 1, 4, 2]]),index=index, columns=columns1)
```

```
               Sector    A   B       A   B    
Year    country sector                      
2000    country1    A   24  20      30  20   
                    B   16  14      10  25   
        country2    A   28  22      6   28   
                    B   11  10      10  4   
2001    country1    A   6   7       12  16  
                    B   19  24      6   9   
        country2    A   22  9       10  15  
                    B   9   1       4   2
```

Thanks to Shubham Sharma answers [multiindex column and rows match if the column and row names are similar and exclude the values from adding in those cell python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76446671/multiindex-column-and-rows-match-if-the-column-and-row-names-are-similar-and-exc) I am able to get the column labeled total. which is simply horizontal summation excluding matching level one row index and level zero column index.

```
#to match the same countries from index and column then exclude the matching cell from addition
ix = df.index.get_level_values(1) 
cx = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
m = ix.values[:, None] == cx.values

df[('TOTAL','EX')] = df.mask(m).sum(axis=1)
df[('TOTAL','GR')] = df.iloc[:,:-1].sum(axis=1)
```

```
resulting df
```

```
               Country  country1    country2  TOTAL 
               Sector    A   B       A   B    EX    GR
Year    country sector                      
2000    country1    A   24  20      30  20   50.0   94
                    B   16  14      10  25   35.0   65
        country2    A   28  22      6   28   50.0   84
                    B   11  10      10  4    21.0   35
2001    country1    A   6   7       12  16   28.0   41
                    B   19  24      6   9    15.0   58
        country2    A   22  9       10  15   31.0   56
                    B   9   1       4   2    10.0   16
```

now I want to proceed and use element-wise division along the column (axis=1).

`df.iloc[:,:-2] = df.iloc[:,:-2].div(df[('TOTAL','GR')].values,axis=1)`

which gives me
ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 4: given 8
this is because this doesnt take into account the year index. but if there is only a single year this result would have given me the expected result nicely. but I want to do it each year. taking into account the level.
what I want the final df look like

````
               Country      country1       country2         TOTAL   
               Sector      A        B        A      B         EX    GR
Year    country sector                      
2000    country1    A   24/94   20/65      30/84    20/35    50.0   94
                    B   16/94   14/65      10/84    25/35    35.0   65
        country2    A   28/94   22/65       6/84    28/35    50.0   84
                    B   11/94   10/65      10/84    4/35     21.0   35
2001    country1    A   6/41    7/58       12/56    16/16    28.0   41
                    B   19/41   24/58       6/56    9/16     15.0   58
        country2    A   22/41   9/58       10/56    15/16    31.0   56
                    B   9/41    1/58        4/56    2/16    10.0    16```
````

I have seen the documentation for df.div and tried to include level 1 to group by year while dividing element-wise division but the same error appeared

```
df.iloc[:,:-2] = df.iloc[:,:-2].div(df[('TOTAL','GR')].values,axis=1, level=1)
```

ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 4: given 8
maybe I am doing the whole thing not right, so i accept any easy work arround recommendations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```py
def fn(x):
    x.iloc[:, :-2] = x.iloc[:, :-2].div(x[('TOTAL', 'GR')].values, axis=1)
    return x

x = df.groupby(level='Year', group_keys=False).apply(fn)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
country               country1            country2           TOTAL     
sector                   agri1     cons2     agri1     cons2    EX   GR
country  Year sector                                                   
country1 2000 agri1   0.493671  0.443038  0.037975  0.025316   790  790
         2001 agri1   0.444444  0.503704  0.014815  0.037037   675  675
         2000 cons2   0.493671  0.443038  0.037975  0.025316   790  790
         2001 cons2   0.444444  0.503704  0.014815  0.037037   675  675
country2 2000 agri1   0.493671  0.443038  0.037975  0.025316   790  790
         2001 agri1   0.444444  0.503704  0.014815  0.037037   675  675
         2000 cons2   0.493671  0.443038  0.037975  0.025316   790  790
         2001 cons2   0.444444  0.503704  0.014815  0.037037   675  675
```

---

Initial `df` is from your question:

```
country              country1       country2       TOTAL     
sector                  agri1 cons2    agri1 cons2    EX   GR
country  Year sector                                         
country1 2000 agri1       390   350       30    20   790  790
         2001 agri1       300   340       10    25   675  675
         2000 cons2       390   350       30    20   790  790
         2001 cons2       300   340       10    25   675  675
country2 2000 agri1       390   350       30    20   790  790
         2001 agri1       300   340       10    25   675  675
         2000 cons2       390   350       30    20   790  790
         2001 cons2       300   340       10    25   675  675
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful you saved my day. could you help me understand why
```df.iloc[:,:-2] = df.iloc[:,:-2].div(df[('TOTAL','GR')].values,axis=1,level=1)```doesn't work. i added the level parameter as mentioned in the documentation

Comment: @Andreja the error disappears but different result.  not my expected result

Comment: @埃塞ABELA oh, so my assumption was wrong :) But the `.groupby()` solution should work.